# Reemplazar valores en una matriz con un bucle

Tags: python, numpy

Mi pregunta es muy básica porque estoy empezando ahora con Python.

Quiero crear una matriz 10*10 y reemplazar los valores por i * j en las posiciones que i y j son pares.

Yo lo he hecho de forma "artesanal" y me gustaría saber como hacerlo con un bucle, pues lo he probado de diversas formas y no obtengo el resultado correcto.

Esta es la forma artesanal que he usado:

```
#Importo la librería numpy y la renombro como np.
import numpy as np
#Creo la matriz I de medida 10x10 y con elementos de valor 0.
I = np.zeros((10,10)).astype(int)

#Las posiciones pares de la matriz son:
#[2,2], [2,4], [2,6], [2,8], [4,2], [4,4], [4,6], [4,8], [6,2], [6,4], [6,6], [6,8], [8,2], [8,4], [8,6], [8,8] 
#En estas posiciones, I[i,j] = i * j
I[2,2] = 2 * 2
I[2,4] = 2 * 4
I[2,6] = 2 * 6
I[2,8] = 2 * 8
I[4,2] = 4 * 2
I[4,4] = 4 * 4
I[4,6] = 4 * 6
I[4,8] = 4 * 8
I[6,2] = 6 * 2
I[6,4] = 6 * 4
I[6,6] = 6 * 6
I[6,8] = 6 * 8
I[8,2] = 8 * 4
I[8,4] = 8 * 4
I[8,6] = 8 * 6
I[8,8] = 8 * 8

#Imprimo el resultado.
print(I)
```

Answer (score 2):

Necesitas dos bucles anidados, uno que itere por las filas pares y otro que, por cada fila, itere por las columnas pares.

Te lo pongo en pseudocódigo para dejarte que lo pases a código tu mismo, que es la mejor forma de aprender. Si te atascas pregunta de nuevo.

```
para cada i, desde 0 hasta 10, de 2 en 2:
   para cada j, desde 0 hasta 10 de 2 en 2:
      I[i,j] = i*j
```

Otra posibilidad, si no sabes cómo hacer el bucle para que vaya de 2 en 2, es ir de 1 en 1 pero asignar el elemento sólo si tanto `i` como `j` son pares:

```
para cada i de 0 a 10:
   para cada j de 0 a 10:
      si (i es par) and (j es par):
         I[i,j] = i*j
```

Puedes mirar si un número `n` es par mirando si el resto de dividir por 2 sale cero, es decir si `n%2==0`.

Answer (score 0):

Es tal cual @abulafia dice, el código sería más o menos así:

```
import numpy as np

I = np.zeros((10, 10)).astype(int)

for i in range(int(I.shape[0])):
    for j in range(int(I.shape[0])):
        if (i%2==0 and j%2==0):
            I[i,j] = i*j

print(I)
```

Comment: Pero déjale pensarlo a él, hombre! :-)

Comment: me he hecho spoiler de las respuestas y ya he visto el código, igualmente haré el ejercicio de comprender su funcionamiento para ser capaz de realizarlo por mi cuenta.
Muchas gracias por vuestra ayuda.